# Custom task pane header in Microsoft Outlook addin

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have created the Outlook addin (which opens in compose email window), and specified displaName and iconUrl in manifest.xml like below:

```
<DisplayName DefaultValue="My Office Addin" />
<IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/sample.png" />
```

Which reflects Icon and Name in below images (1. OptionMenu and 2. Sidepane).

[image: Menu option]
[image: SidePane]

**I am having few questions regarding it:**

**1. Is there any option to disable or hide this icon and title in sidepane(2nd image)?**

**2. Is there any option to customize header of sidepane(2nd image) like setting background image or custom font in header?**

I have gone through microsoft documentation in last few days but I have found no solution. I am new to Microsoft add-in's. Please help me if you have any idea regarding this.
Here is my manifest.xml file:

```
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>1e4f9008-e850-4631-be7c-d36b05a23543</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>My Office Addin</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="My Office Addin" />
  <Description DefaultValue="My Office Addin Description" />
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/sample.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/sample.png" />
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="Mailbox" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
      <TabletSettings>
        <!-- Change the following line to specify     -->
        <!-- the web server that hosts the HTML file. -->
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue=
          "https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
        <RequestedHeight>216</RequestedHeight>
      </TabletSettings>
    </Form>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
      </DesktopSettings>
      <TabletSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
      </TabletSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently these capabilities (customizing the task pane header and setting the icon's visibility) are not available for add-ins. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Comment: Though this is some time ago and the link provided is not valid anymore, but is there a solution to this already? Because if I take a look at the Script Lab Office AddIn in Word or Excel, the header of the pane is changed when clicked on the ribbon-button.

Comment: Currently, these capabilities (customizing the task pane header and setting the icon's visibility) are not available for add-ins. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered when we go through our planning process.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform

Comment: My question is not Outlook-specific. Of this is not possible yet, how is it possible that in the "Script Lab AddIn" the title is changed when switching tabs?

Comment: Can you please explain what is use case you are trying to handle and on which product (Word/Outlook)?

Comment: When switching panels in Word, I would like to change the title of the taskpane. An example can be seen in the script-lab AddIn. When I click "Code" the title is of the taskpane is "Code", when I click "Run" from the menu, the title of the new taskpane is "Run"

Comment: This capability is not currently applicable for Outlook add-ins. There are differences in the add-in UX for each office client and right now Outlook add-ins do not have what word add-ins have - in terms of customizing the taskpane headers.

Answer (score 2):

The answers are "no" and "no". There is nothing you will be able to do. This area is not customizable and every client(application) implements its own way to display the information from the manifest.

For example, Outlook for Web would display the name of the add-on and the icon provided ...
[image]

In the same time, Outlook Desktop for Windows would display just the name of the add-on ...
[image]